# connecting to questDB with libpqxx

Tags: postgresql, libpqxx

Im having an issue connecting to QuestDB with libpqxx, i can establish a connection using the postgresql client as per the instructions here:
https://questdb.io/docs/guidePSQL

however, when i go to connect to QuestDB, using my simple program, that is more-or-less a slightly modified version of the standard "get me started" program:
https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

int main(){
   try
   {
    pqxx::connection C(
    "user=admin "
    "hostaddr=127.0.0.1 "
    "password=quest "
    "dbname=qdb"
    "port=8812 ");


  std::cout << "Connected to " << C.dbname() << std::endl;
  pqxx::work W{C};

  pqxx::result R{W.exec("SELECT name FROM employee")};

  std::cout << "Found " << R.size() << "employees:\n";
  for (auto row: R)
     std::cout << row[0].c_str() << '\n';

  std::cout << "Doubling all employees' salaries...\n";
  W.exec0("UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*2");

  std::cout << "Making changes definite: ";
  W.commit();
  std::cout << "OK.\n";
 }
 catch (std::exception const &e)
 {
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
 }
   return 0;
}
```

.. i get an error:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

what also complicates things possibly, is i cannot find anywhere pg_hba.conf ,are these even still a thing in version 10 of postgresql? i have /usr/lib/postgresql/10 but no config files.. and ive also searched the machine.. nothing found. any help would be much appreciated.

thankyou

Answer (score 5):

The official documentation for `libpqxx` states that:

> The connection string consists of attribute=value pairs separated by spaces, e.g. "user=john password=1x2y3z4". [reference](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx)

Your connection string is:

```
    pqxx::connection C(
"user=admin "
"hostaddr=127.0.0.1 "
"password=quest "
"dbname=qdb"
"port=8812 ");
```

You are missing a space after `qdb`, so the correct connection string is:

```
    pqxx::connection C(
"user=admin "
"hostaddr=127.0.0.1 "
"password=quest "
"dbname=qdb "
"port=8812 ");
```

I just tried it and it works fine for me.

On a second hand, the following SQL statement:

```
 W.exec0("UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*2");
```

Will not work, `UPDATE` is not supported **yet** by QuestDB. You can find more details about SQL support on the official documentation, [here](https://questdb.io/docs/concept/sql-execution-order/).